# Send Grid Mailer events

Tags: apex

I am using sendgrid to send multiple emails. I want to get the events of emails (opened,delivered,bounce,...) how can i achieve help me.

Is there any method to get the details of these emails ?

Comment: Can you explain what sendgrid is, how you're using this with salesforce and elaborate on what you want to do ? We try to specialize in answering specific problems, and not so much questions of life. Have you looked at their documentation ? http://sendgrid.com/docs/

Comment: I am using to send mails through sendgrid and after sending i want to know the mail events as explained above

Comment: How are you doing this .. is this a package installed in your org, have you set up an integration, ifso through apex, messages, middleware, ... ? We can not guess your problem, you have to explain it full, with sufficient background and detail so that we can understand it. We want to help.

Comment: It is installed package in my application, now i have one vf page with button(events) so i want to fetch these events in that button using controller

Answer (score 2):

one way to do this is to create a public facing site in visualforce, and use the sendgrid webhooks to trigger a post to your public facing site. More information can be found here: http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/

Comment: How to set that urls in controller class any xamples

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking?

Comment: I need to view that email statistics results in vf page through controller(that means i have a button in vf page when ever i click on vf page it needs to display)

Comment: so, you'll first need to setup the web hooks and some custom objects to store the data from send grid. Once that's done, you'll have objects you can query to show stats on the vf page. Just create the vf page, create a button to pass in the params you need, and write the soql queries to find the data associated. The webhooks will create records whenever an activity is made by the email. ie: it's opened etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in checking MassMailer which a native appexchange app. In this app, you can fetch the events of email(opened,delivered, bounces etc...). Please check the link below:

http://www.mansasys.com/massmailer

A nice blog post that covers details about this app at
http://www.mansasys.com/blog/what-you-need-to-know-about-salesforce-mass-email-limits-and-options/

Thanks
AK

Comment: It seems massmailer has been purchased - here is a valid link to massmailer now  https://massmailer.io/ -and- https://sendgrid.com/partners/massmailer/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a REST web service in Salesforce Apex that will accept the Event Data. The Event Data is sent by SendGrid in a format that has to be parsed by you, instead of by the builtin Salesforce JSON processor. So in my POST method, notice there is no argument specified.

Here's what my REST class looks like:

```
@RestResource (urlMapping='/SendEventToMyOrg/*')
global with sharing class SendGridEvent {
    global class SendGridEventDTO {
        public String email;
        public Long timestamp;
        public String event;
        public SendGridEventDTO() {}
    } 

    @HttpPost
    global static void sendEventToMe() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        List<SendGridEventDTO> eventList = 
            (List<SendGridEventDTO>)JSON.deserialize( request.requestBody.toString(),
            List<SendGridEventDTO>.class );
        if ( eventList != null && eventList.size() > 0 ) {
            // do something useful here
        }
    }
}
```

Then in SendGrid, under the Event app setting, the URL to enter is something like: http://na1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/SendEventToMyOrg

I'm working on the authentication part of this puzzle now.